# How to select screens for RealVNC fullscreen mode with “UseAllMonitors”

Tags: vnc

RealVNC has a very handy fullscreen mode that supports spanning multiple monitors (UseAllMonitors=1) Does anyone know if there is a way to tell it to use "some" monitors (two out of three) instead of "all"? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no option for 'some' monitors, sorry. You can only select one or all.